# Change FontScale on xamarin Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm developing a app on xamarin forms PCL.
I want to force my app to have FontScale normal (1), because if a user have extra large text defined on system, that will crash some features on my app.

I tried to do that on MainActivity android

```
Android.Content.Res.Resources.System.Configuration.FontScale = 1;
```

But that has no effect. Someone knows if that is possible ?

Comment: Fix your crash rather than messing the font scale.

Comment: @Cheesebaron I don't think that's possible. I'm using PrintService to print some html, I have all font size set, but when the scale is different than normal it will print all wrong. So I think the best solution would be that.

Comment: How about changing the font size on the WebView then?

Comment: @Cheesebaron I'm already doing that, because my webview is constructed from my html, and all elements have text size set. 
When FontScale is changed all elements is changed too